# divide 2 decimal numbers where the result is known to be int

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to divide 2 very large double numbers and result is known to be int only. I am getting result either 1 less or 1 more if I use Math.ceil or cast to int. What is the best way to do this.

I have tried type casting and Math.ceil function.

```
double num1=sum-totalsum;
double d=(num1*totalmul);

double diff=mul-totalmul;
double missing=d/diff;
double repeated=missing+num1;
System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(repeated)+" "+(int)Math.ceil(missing));
```

expected result is int. repeated and missing are always int.

Comment: What do you mean by "divide 2 very large double numbers and result is known to be int only"? That the result of  the division __will__ always be a natural number only or that you only __care__ about the value before the decimal separator? Because the first part is very unlikely due to the imprecision of `double`. Also, since you're using multiple unknown variables here, can you provide real examples/values?

Comment: result is always natural number.
for 
d= 1.1809311961584165E39
diff=5.13448346155833E37
I am getting value for missing is 23.00000000000001 which should be 23.0. missing will always be natural number as per the pre condition/logic set in the program. How can I get the missing to 23.0

Comment: Can you provide values for all variables, so we can calculate the numbers as well?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is `Math.round()`

So:

```
System.out.println((int)Math.round(repeated)+" "+(int)Math.round(missing));
```

Comment: can we limit decimal points to 2 digit maximum in this operation
double missing=d/diff;
 rather using Math.round operation

Comment: not directly but try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary